# Guard running outside of Bundler warning

Tags: ruby, guard

When I run the `guard` command it gives the following warning:

> Guard here! It looks like your project has a Gemfile, yet you are
>   running `guard` outside of Bundler. If this is your intent, feel free
>   to ignore this message. Otherwise, consider using `bundle exec guard`
>   to ensure your dependencies are loaded correctly.

Is this hinting to me that Rails is not configured to work with Bundler correctly, or is it normal? It's not the expected behavior in the tutorial I'm following.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `bundle exec guard` instead. Or, alternatively, run `bundle install --binstubs`, then you may run guard with `bin/guard` (it creates a script at this location). This is the recommended way of running all commands coming from gems installed with `bundle install`.

(If I understand it correctly) It ensures that you run the specific version of the gem specified in the bundle as well as that this gem will not be able to run gems which are installed on you computer but not included in the Gemfile (which could fool you into believing that you project is fine until you try to run it on a different computer, or a production server, where the other gem would be missing). It also does a lot of of stuff which, frankly, I have no idea about.

More info [in the docs](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html).